# Why my CPP running randomly after end of the program

Tags: c++, gdb

When I try to run my program in GDB. After the end of the main, instead of end of the program, my program start to jumping back to the middle of my main and then jumping randomly (not forward).
Let say my main have lines between 57 and 161. When the program finish 161, it start to jump to line 67 and then it jump to line 64, then line 61, and then jump forward to 145, and finally jump to line 161 and then end the program. The program didn't do the jumping and first run (57->58->59->..->67->68->69->..->161), after it go to the end of main (161), it start to do the jump as I describe. I didn't use and goto or labeling in my program. It just start to do random jumping after the end of main instead of end the program.

Here is some output from my gdb:

```
145   evolve1.RVpotentialSample[0].outputHist((char*)"data/potentialHistS",sampleSize/10);
(gdb) n
67      Action sample1;
(gdb) n
64      velocity_verlet_cell_SBC evolve1(number_of_particles*2,dt,sampleSize);
(gdb) n
61      initial_MC_SBC initial1(number_of_particles,temp,100*number_of_particles);
(gdb) n
145   evolve1.RVpotentialSample[0].outputHist((char*)"data/potentialHistS",sampleSize/10);
(gdb) n
161 }
(gdb) n
```

I don't even know how can this happen. Gdb just show me some strange jumping at the end of program. Thanks for any possible input.

Comment: Is the jumping always the same or is it random? Unless it's a bug with GDB you're probably better off posting the bits of your code you think are to blame.

Comment: Are you debugging an optimized build?  If so, then one explanation could be that the source code does not match the actual executable due to optimizations being used.

Comment: @Michael The jumping is not random actually, but it is just unexpected, it always happen in a fix sequence. My code is very mess, also it including lots of class. It will be quite confuse to post all the code here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I also notice some post say optimization may cause unexpected result in gdb, so I already add -O0 flag to my gcc compiler.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GDB but are these not destructors being called as objects go out of scope?

Comment: @Fibbles i also have set a break point at my destructor before. And after all the destructor, it start to jumping as what I describe.

Comment: @WanChap: In addition to your destructors, some library objects have destructors (`std::cout` will flush and close its output file descriptor, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two usual reasons for the behavior you observed:

1. you built your program with optimization (`-O2` or similar flag), or
2. you have local variables of class type with destructors.

If the first case, you would normally observe the program "jumping around" all the time (not just at the end of the program), as the compiler re-arranges instructions such that the line order is no longer sequential.

In the second case, the compiler usually "calls" the destructor from the same line where the variable was declared.

> also have set a break point at my destructor before. And after all the destructor, it start to jumping as what I describe

You are likely mistaken. When the program jumps back, execute a few `stepi` commands. There is a high chance that you'll land inside a destructor that you haven't set a break point on.

Comment: First, thanks for point out the two possibility.

The first possible shouldn't be the case, since I use -O0 and it didn't jumping around at begin, it only start after the end of main.

So I think it is very high chance be the second case. I don't quite understand the second scenario. Local variable means variable declare in main? I do have my own class with own define destructors that is declare in my main. So this will cause problem? If I declare outside main, is that means can solve the problem?

Comment: @WanChap You *don't* have a problem to solve, but yes: moving the variable outside of `main` will cause it to be destructed at program exit, rather than at the end of `main`.

Comment: I may understand what you mean now. So those jump in gdb is actually where the constructor is, but instead of running the constructor again, it actually run the destructor. So nothing wrong is happening, the code didn't run the same line again. Thanks Russian.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: The program exits at the end of `main`.  For some other function, the difference would be important.  Here, not so much (his debugger is still going to step through all those destructors when reaching the end of `main`).  Actually, global variables have problems that locals in main don't have, namely unsequenced construction order between compilation units (static initialization fiasco) which also affects destruction.